# Unable to get Solve or FindRoot to work for trigonometric functions, even when answer is known

Tags: equation-solving

Maybe I am missing a fundamental part of Mathematica that I am simply unaware of, but it seems that either `Solve` or `FindRoot` should be able to find the solution I am looking for. Just for verification, you can see that when I plug in the solutions the variable evaluates to exactly what I am looking for. Sorry if this is something basic, but this is very frustrating :(

#### Edit

Ask and you shall receive...

```
Clear[alpha, theta1, theta2, theta3, AtU, UtB, Dmat, A, B, a1, a2,b1, b2, psi, psi0, psi1, Dmat, d1, d2, d3, d4, params]

alpha = Pi/2;
theta3 = Pi/2;
U = buildU[alpha, theta1, theta2, theta3] // Simplify;

psi = {psi0, 0, psi1, 0};

A = IdentityMatrix[2];
B = IdentityMatrix[2];

AtU = ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[A, U]];
UtB = ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[ConjugateTranspose[U], B]];

Dmat = DiagonalMatrix[{d1, d2, d3, d4}]
finalMat = UtB.Dmat.AtU.psi // Simplify;

Print["phi"]
phi = 
  FullSimplify[finalMat[[1 ;; 2]], {Element[theta1, Reals], Element[theta2, Reals]}]
Print["psi"]
psi = B.H.A.{psi0, psi1} // Simplify

Print["Test eq1."]
eq1 = (phi[[1]] == 1/Sqrt[2] psi[[1]]) /. {psi0 -> 0} // Simplify
eq2 = (phi[[1]] == 1/Sqrt[2] psi[[1]]) /. {psi1 -> 0} // Simplify
eq3 = (phi[[2]] == 1/Sqrt[2] psi[[2]]) /. {psi0 -> 0} // Simplify
eq4 = (phi[[2]] == 1/Sqrt[2] psi[[2]]) /. {psi1 -> 0} // Simplify

params = {d1, d2, d3, d4}
{d1, d2, d3, d4} = 
   ({d1, d2, d3, d4} /. 
      Flatten[Normal /@ Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}]]) // Simplify;
{d1, d2, d3, d4} = 
  {d1, d2, d3, d4} /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0, C[4] -> 0}
d2
FindRoot[Abs[d2] == 1, {{theta1, Pi/2}, {theta2, Pi/2}}]
Solve[Abs[d2] == 1, {theta1, theta2}]
Abs[d2] /. {theta1 -> Pi/2, theta2 -> Pi/2}
```

Comment: Post copiable code, not pictures.

Comment: For `FindRoot`, I think you need 2 equations when you have 2 unknowns. This gives me a result: `FindRoot[{Abs[d2] == 
   1, \[Theta]2^2 + 2 \[Theta]2 + 
    1 == (\[Theta]2 + 1)^2}, {{\[Theta]1, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Theta]2, \[Pi]/
    2}}]`.

Comment: Do you have code that I could evaluate myself?

Comment: Thanks people, code posted. This equation is a simple variant for test purposes before I expand to more complicated spaces. As far as the two equations go I don't know if that is necessary, shouldn't mathematica be able to find when equation is satisfiable with only one?

Comment: That code does not run for me. Missing definition for `buildU`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) can handle the equation, with a little help.  One problem is that you have one equation with two unknowns.  `FindRoot` almost certainly cannot handle that.  `Solve` might try, but you are explicitly asking for a solution for the pair of unknowns; while it may seem impossible, `Solve` sometimes gives a partial solution.  Instead you might try to solving for just one variable.  It happens that there is a "full-dimensional" component, in the lingo of `Solve`, which `Solve` declines to deal with.

`Reduce` can produce a conditional solution of one variable in terms of another.  A little processing can simplify the answer:

```
Reduce[Abs[Csc[u]*I*Exp[-I v]] == 1 &&
 -Infinity < Re[v] < Infinity && -Infinity < Re[u] < Infinity, v]
FullSimplify@%
solset = Reduce[%, {v}]
(*
  Im[Log[1/Abs[Csc[u]]]] == 0 && Abs[Csc[u]] > 0 && Im[v] == Re[Log[1/Abs[Csc[u]]]]
  Im[v] + Log[Abs[Csc[u]]] == 0
  Im[Log[Abs[Csc[u]]]] == 0 && Im[v] == -Re[Log[Abs[Csc[u]]]]
*)
```

One can use the answer to find particular solutions:

```
FindInstance[solset, {u, v}]
Abs[Csc[u]*I*Exp[-I v]] /. % // FullSimplify
(*
  {{u -> -(13/5) + (39 I)/10, v -> -(9/10) + I Log[Abs[Sinh[39/10 + (13 I)/5]]]}}
  {1}
*)
```

It is also possible to reduce the condition further:

```
solsetRefined = 
 solset /. (udom : Im[Log[Abs[Csc[u]]]]) == 0 :> 
   FullSimplify[FunctionDomain[udom, u] && Im[Log[Abs[Csc[u]]]] == 0]
(*
  u/π ∉ Integers && C[1] ∈ Integers &&
    (-π < u - 2 π C[1] < 0 || 0 < u - 2 π C[1] < π) && Im[v] == -Re[Log[Abs[Csc[u]]]]
*)
```

This speeds up `FindInstance`.

```
FindInstance[solset, {u, v}] // AbsoluteTiming
FindInstance[solsetRefined /. C[1] -> 0, {u, v}] // AbsoluteTiming
FindInstance[solsetRefined /. C[1] -> 1, {u, v}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.380929, {{u -> -(13/5) + (39 I)/10, 
     v -> -(9/10) + I Log[Abs[Sinh[39/10 + (13 I)/5]]]}}}
  {0.067772, {{u -> -(7/3), v -> -(1/2) + I Log[Sin[7/3]]}}}
  {0.073675, {{u -> 130/33, v -> -(1/2) + I Log[-Sin[130/33]]}}}
*)
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks so much for the in-depth response!